# Why isn't my include directive working in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, include, compilation

I'm working on some code that uses [Open Dynamics Engine](http://www.ode.org/).  I've worked with this code before on windows, but now I'm moving over to unix so I can get experience working with C under a unix environment and so I'm not reliant on visual studio.  I downloaded everything to my home directory, built using the included makefile and tried a demo; everything's good.  I made a directory and a test file in it with my own test.  For my #include I specified:

```
#include ".././ode-0.11.1/include/ode/ode.h"
#include ".././ode-0.11.1/include/drawstuff/drawstuff.h"
```

Since the library is just located in my home directory and not in the standard location.  I go to compile my code but:

```
.././ode-0.11.1/include/ode/ode.h:28:27: fatal error: ode/odeconfig.h: No such 
file or directory
```

Looking at ode.h, it includes a bunch of other headers all located in the same directory, but using the bracket syntax instead of quotes.  I'm guessing this has something to do with why gcc can't locate the other headers.  I've looked at the makefiles but don't know enough to figure out what my issue is.  Why is my compilation not working?  A detailed/thorough answer would be appreciated since I want to learn how this all works (linking, includes, make, etc.).

Edit: So I figured out how to include the headers correctly, now I need to figure out how to link to the library definitions for the functions...

Edit2: Still can't figure out how to link to my code.  The compiled static libraries get dumped in '~/ode-0.11.1/ode/src/.libs' and '~/ode-0.11.1/drawstuff/src/.libs' for the drawing functions.

Edit3: I think I figured it out.  I wasn't using the -l option correctly, and it seems like it has to go AFTER the files that reference functions from the libraries I'm linking to.

Comment: It might help to see your makefile and which directory your code s in - Note your code should not be in any of the ode directories

Comment: At the moment I'm not using a makefile of my own since I'm just compiling 1 file.  It's located in `~/code/myfile.cpp`

Comment: SO what produces the ~/ode-0.11.1/ode/src/.libs if it is the ode makefile -then I suspect you should also do a make install

Comment: Yes I believe they are created by the makefile.  I didn't try make install yet (like I said I'm new to all this) but I presume that will install the libraries to `/usr/lib` or somewhere?  I was going to try copying the libs there manually to see if that did the trick. Would that have the same effect as `make install`?

Comment: possibly the same but better to use make install - the configuration before build might be able to change the install directory

Comment: I tried it but the only thing that changed is that I no longer need to specify the include path, gcc still can't find the libraries which are now at `/usr/local/lib`.  The other issue is that the install only copied the core ODE library and not the drawstuff library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the include directory in the compile line

e.g.

```
gcc -I.././ode-0.11.1/include
```

or better in this cas an absolute path

Then in code include like

```
#include "ode/ode.h"
#include "drawstuff/drawstuff.h"
```

Thus all the files included from ode.h will be accessed from the same directory. Your example ode/odeconfig.h would be found as ode is a subdirectoy from the include path in the -I parameter.

Linking is similar but both parts done on the command line .The two parts are file given by a -l variable and the directory the lib is in by -L parameter. Also if the library is say libode.dylib the you just meed the name e.g. ode.

So command line is

```
gcc -lode -L.././ode-0.11.1/lib
```

Comment: Yeah I was able to get it to find the headers using '#include <ode/ode.h>' and '#include <drawstuff/drawstuff.h>'and specifying the path as you described, however it still can't find the definitions for the functions.  The compiled '.lo' files all get dumped in '~/ode-0.11.1/ode/src/' which I tried specifying using the '-L' flag but it didn't work.

Comment: Ah object files - you need to give the full path for each file - are you compiling ode or a program using the ode library

Comment: Yes I am, my code is in a separate directory.  But couldn't I just link to the *.a files at the paths mentioned in my original post (2nd edit)?

Comment: Just read my comment above and realized I don't really answer your question.  Right now I'm compiling code that uses the ODE library, I can compile ode itself just fine using the included makefile.

Answer (score 0):

go to directory ode-0.11.1
This will be the project's home.

So include files belong to directory ode-0.11.1/include
In this case your source should be like

myprog.c

```
#include "ode/ode.h"
#include "drawstuff/drawstuff.h"
```

compilation command should be a line like:

```
gcc -I./include/ode -I./include/drawstuff  myprog.c -o myprog
```

Command executed in directory ode-0.11.1/include

Comment: That will not work as you have ode or drawstuff in both the include and the -I path it can only be in one to find the root include and has to be the way I give to allow the files in ode.h to be included.